# When attempting to delete a product, the associated files (image and PDF) in S3 are not getting deleted in node js

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, mern, google-api-nodejs-client

```
const deleteFilesFromS3 = async (fileKeys) => {
  const s3 = new aws.S3({
    accessKeyId: accessKeyId,
    secretAccessKey: secretAccessKey,
    region: region,
  });

  // Iterate through fileKeys and delete each file from S3
  for (const fileKey of fileKeys) {
    const params = {
      Bucket: "thenaturebeautyflower",
      Key: fileKey,
    };

    try {
      await s3.deleteObject(params).promise();
      console.log(`File deleted successfully: ${fileKey}`);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(`Error deleting file from S3: ${fileKey}`, error);
    }
  }
};
```

> **File deleted successfully: https://thenaturebeautyflower.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/pool/images/%20BERL%C3%8DN%20filter-1702962944491-3-Berlin.jpg
> ProductState.js:156 File deleted successfully:
> https://thenaturebeautyflower.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/pool/pdf/%20BERL%C3%8DN%20filter-1702962944491-BERLIN.pdf**

but still image and pdf file is present in s3 console ?

Comment: [If attempting to delete an object that does not exist, Amazon S3 will return a success message instead of an error message](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3Client.html#deleteObject-com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.DeleteObjectRequest-).
Please double-check the keys that you are trying to delete (it seems they contain some URL-encoded characters)

Comment: https://thenaturebeautyflower.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/pool/pdf/Aster-1703610277001-ASTER.pdf
when i click on delete option message in console is file deleted successfully with this link....but whemn i click on this a pdf file shown in browser,and pdf file is also exist in s3 console...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    const deleteFilesFromS3 = async (fileKeys) => {
  // Creating an S3 client with AWS credentials
  const s3 = new aws.S3({
    accessKeyId: accessKeyId,
    secretAccessKey: secretAccessKey,
    region: region,
  });

  // Specify the common prefix to be removed
  const prefixToRemove = 'https://thenaturebeautyflower.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/';

  // Iterate through fileKeys and delete each file from S3
  for (const fileKey of fileKeys) {
    // Remove the specified prefix from the file key
    const keyWithoutPrefix = fileKey.replace(prefixToRemove, '');

    // Determine the appropriate prefix based on the file type
    const fileTypePrefix = fileKey.includes('images/') ? 'images/' : 'pdf/';

    // Add the fileTypePrefix to the filename
    const fileName = `${fileTypePrefix}${keyWithoutPrefix.split('/').pop()}`;

    // Specify the parameters for deleting an object from S3
    const params = {
      Bucket: "thenaturebeautyflower",
      Key: keyWithoutPrefix,
      VersionId: 'null'
    };

    console.log(fileName);

    try {
      // Attempt to delete the object from S3
      await s3.deleteObject(params).promise();
      console.log(`File deleted successfully: ${fileKey}`);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(`Error deleting file from S3: ${fileKey}`, error);
    }
  }
};
```

my mistake was that i was puuting complete address in filname under params which was wrong  we should only contain a folder/filaname.extention only